# how to redirect groceryCrud operation links with json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json, grocery-crud, codeigniter-3

I have a forms of crud operations of groceryCrud where I put them in a modal. Inside the datatable, there's a button where I choose to edit, view or delete records. Inside of those button functions are the code mentioned above. In the codes above, when I click the edit button, it will display a modal with the edit form and so forth with others. At the list.php, I declare a JavaScript variables below where I get the edit and view links from groceryCrud.

The problem is, I can't get the ID of the selected data inside the datatable when I click the edit and view button. It will get and display the latest inputted data/record in the modal. Is there anything wrong on declaring my JavaScript variables that's why I can't get exactly the link with the exact ID of my selected record to be performed with crud operations?

I have a code at `datatables/view/list.php`

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-vcenter table-condensed table-responsive table-hover" id="example-datatable" style="height: 50px;">
<thead>
    <tr>
<center>
    <?php foreach ($columns as $column) {?>
        <th><?php echo $column->display_as;?></th>
    <?php }
    ?>
    <?php if (!$unset_delete || !$unset_edit || !$unset_read || !empty($actions)) {?>
        <th class="text-center actions" title="Actions" data-sortable="false"><i class="fa fa-flash"></i></th>
    <?php }
?>
</center>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($list as $num_row => $row) {
?>
    <tr id='row-<?php echo $num_row?>'>
        <?php foreach ($columns as $column) {?>
            <td><?php echo $row->{$column->field_name}?></td>
        <?php }
?>
        <?php if (!$unset_delete || !$unset_edit || !$unset_read || !empty($actions)) {
    ?>
            <td class="text-center">
                <?php
if (!empty($row->action_urls)) {
        foreach ($row->action_urls as $action_unique_id => $action_url) {
            $action = $actions[$action_unique_id];
            ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo $action_url;?>" class="edit_button btn btn-small btn-effect-ripple btn-ripple btn-default row col-sm-4 col-xs-4" role="button">
                            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon <?php echo $action->css_class;?> <?php echo $action_unique_id;?>"></span><span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;<?php echo $action->label?></span>
                        </a>
                        <?php
}
    }
    ?>
                <?php if (!$unset_read) {?>
        <!--                    <a href="<?php // echo $row->read_url              ?>" class="edit_button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button">
        <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-document"></span>
        <span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;<?php // echo $this->l('list_view');                ?></span>
        </a>-->
                    <a href="#modal-fadeView" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-xs btn-primary viewBtn" data-toggle="modal" title="<?php echo $this->l('list_view');?>" role="button" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                        <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i>
                    </a>
                <?php }
    ?>

                <?php if (!$unset_edit) {?>
                                                                                                                                                                                <!--                    <a href="<?php // echo $row->edit_url              ?>" class="edit_button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button">
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                <span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;<?php // echo $this->l('list_edit');                ?></span>
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        </a>-->
                    <a href="#modal-fadeEdit" class="edit_button btn btn-effect-ripple btn-xs btn-success editBtn" data-toggle="modal" title="<?php echo $this->l('list_edit');?>" role="button" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative;">
                        <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                    </a>
                <?php }
    ?>
                <?php if (!$unset_delete) {?>
        <!--                    <a onclick = "javascript: return delete_row('<?php // echo $row->delete_url               ?>', '<?php // echo $num_row              ?>')"
                            href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete_button ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary" role="button">
                            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-circle-minus"></span>
                            <span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;<?php // echo $this->l('list_delete');                ?></span>
                    </a>-->
                    <a onclick = "javascript: return delete_row('<?php echo $row->delete_url?>', '<?php echo $num_row?>')"
                       href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete_button btn btn-effect-ripple btn-xs btn-danger" title="<?php echo $this->l('list_delete');?>" role="button">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </a>
                <?php }
    ?>
            </td>
        <?php }
?>
    </tr>
<?php }
?>
</tbody>
<!--    <tfoot>
<tr>
<?php foreach ($columns as $column) {?>
                                    <th><input type="text" name="<?php echo     $column->field_name;?>" placeholder="<?php echo $this->l('list_search') . ' ' .     $column->display_as;?>" class="search_<?php echo $column->field_name;?>" /></th>
<?php }
?>
<?php if (!$unset_delete || !$unset_edit || !$unset_read || !empty($actions)) {?>
                                    <th>
                                        <button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only floatR refresh-data" role="button" data-url="<?php echo $ajax_list_url;?>">
                                            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-refresh"></span><span class="ui-button-text">&nbsp;</span>
                                        </button>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" class="clear-filtering ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-primary floatR">
                                            <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-e"></span>
                                            <span class="ui-button-text"><?php echo $this->l('list_clear_filtering');?></span>
                                        </a>
                                    </th>
<?php }
?>
</tr>
</tfoot>-->
</table>

<!--<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>assets/Backend/grocery_crud/js/jquery_plugins/jquery.fancybox.pack-2.1.5.js">    </script>-->
<script type="text/javascript">
var editUrl = "<?php echo $row->edit_url?>",
    readUrl = "<?php echo $row->read_url?>";

var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>
```

inside the `<script>`tag below, I declare the variables of the crud operation links. And I have this js file:

```
        $(".addBtn").click(function () {
            $('#addFrame').attr('src', "/InfoTable/add");
        });

        $(".editBtn").click(function () {
            $('#editFrame').attr('src', editUrl);
        });

        $(".viewBtn").click(function () {
            $('#viewFrame').attr('src', readUrl);
        });
```

Now, I can't get the exact link of the crud operation with the data id, it gets the latest inputted/added data id when I click the button of edit and view.

Comment: You will have to be more specific, there is a lot of spagetii to read through here and without a better idea if what the problem is, not many are going to bother [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: sorry @RiggsFolly, i have a grammar problem that's why i cannot deliver my problem properly, but ill try again to clarify if i may.
i have a forms of crud oprations of groceryCrud where i put them in a modal. Inside the datatable, theres a button where i choose to edit, view or delete records. Inside of those button functions are the code mentioned above. In the codes above, when i click the edit button, it will display a modal with the edit form and so forth with others. At the `list.php`, i declare a javascript variables below where i get the edit and view links from groceryCrud.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The problem is, i cant get the ID of the selected data inside the datatable when i click the edit and view button. It will get and display the latest inputted data/record in the modal. Is there anything wrong on declaring my javascript variables thats why i cant get exactly the link with the exact ID of my selected record to be performed with crud operations?